# Template selection area is not visible on page editor sidebar in wordpress twentty sixteen default theme

Tags: theme-development, page-template

Template selection area is not visible on page editor sidebar in wordpress twentty sixteen default theme

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name:Zoho testAPI
 *
 *
 *
 * 
 */


echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Try a space between : and your template name

Comment: @iantsch you see before any comment sixteen themes

Comment: here are not any options to select template

Answer (score 0):

Twenty Sixteen does not contain any post type templates by default, thus no template selection is shown.

Adding a custom `foo.php` file to the `wp-content/themes/twentysixteen` folder with the following content works just fine and reveals the template selection meta box (title: "Page Attributes"):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Foo Bar
 * Template Post Type: post, page
 */

 // Do some stuff…
```

It also works for pages only using `Template Name` without `Template Post Type`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Foo Bar
 */

 // Do some stuff…
```